# Protobuf field names with numbers are capitalized in a unexpected way

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have a message:

```
message Image {

    string link_40dp = 1;
}
```

After the compilation, in Java, the field name is `link40Dp` (the first letter after a number is capitalized). But, I am expecting, that the field name would be `link40dp` (`d` in lower case).

Is it expected behavior or bug? Are there other corner-cases like this?

I am using `Protobuf Gradle Plugin v0.8.5` and `Protoc v3.6.1` to generate messages in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through sources and found that it is the expected behavior.

See the [code](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_helpers.cc#L161) of the capitalization. All the capitalization rules can be found in the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

The field name was converted from [**snake case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (with underscores) to [**camel case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (with syllable capitals).

Hence for `link_40dp` camel case would deliver `"link" + capitalize("40dp")`.
Where *capitalize(string)* would turn the first letter into a capital.

The Apache commons library would capitalize "40dp" as "40dp" (no change) I think, but evidently here a "smarter" capitalize skips the digits.

This at least signals that the original string contained an underscore: `link_40dp`, `link4_0dp` or `link40_dp`.

So it is an expected behavior, though rather unexpected.